# Flexbox odd Behavior on iOS Mobile Browsers and OS X Safari

Tags: angularjs, sass, webkit, flexbox

I am new to Flexbox because for my job I have to support back to IE8, so I have never really bothered with it until this project.

I am trying to figure out how to make a grid of "cards" have the same heights. These cards contain varying amounts of text inside of them, as well as an image. Since I am using AngularJS the complexity of JavaScript solutions to make this work is more than I have time for, thus I chose flexbox.

This is my relevant code for the card-wrapper (let me know if you need more):

```
.card-grid {
    display: -webkit-box;      /* OLD - iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6 */
    display: -moz-box;         /* OLD - Firefox 19- (buggy but mostly works) */
    display: -ms-flexbox;      /* TWEENER - IE 10 */
    display: -webkit-flex;     /* NEW - Chrome */
    display: flex;             /* NEW, Spec - Opera 12.1, Firefox 20+ */

    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;

    ...

    .data-card {
        height: auto;
        //IE fallback
        display: inline-block;
        //Modern Browsers
        display: -webkit-box;      /* OLD - iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6 */
        display: -moz-box;         /* OLD - Firefox 19- (buggy but mostly works) */
        display: -ms-flexbox;      /* TWEENER - IE 10 */
        display: -webkit-flex;     /* NEW - Chrome */
        display: flex;             /* NEW, Spec - Opera 12.1, Firefox 20+ */

        ...

    }
}
```

And here is the relevant angular HTML for the above selectors:

```
<div class="card-group">
    <ol class="cards card-grid invisible grid-row">
        <li ng-repeat... class="data-card col xs-6 md-4 lg-3">
            <a class="card" href="javascript:void(0)" ... >
                ...
            </a>
        </li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

This is a screen shot of what is happening on Chrome and Safari in iOS:
[image: The problem is it shows the first card, then for some reason or another, the second card is on the next line...]
The issue I am facing is that, it's showing that first card "Axial" and then the next card "Motor Start" Should be right next to it.

Things I've tried:

- Putting the wrap property on the item itself, instead of the wrapper, and that just looked awful
- Defining the width, and using `flex-grow` but axial just goes to 100% width, and so the does very last (not depicted) card with nothing next to it.
- Doing `wrap-reverse` but that just reversed the content and gave me the same problem.

Then I popped open Safari on OS X and got this:
[image: Same issue as on iOS]

It works on:

- Chrome (Desktop)
- Firefox (Desktop)
- Internet Explorer Edge (Desktop)
- Chrome (Andriod)

The only places it's not working are on Apple browsers (i.e. Chrome iOS, and Safari Mobile, etc.)

So I am thinking it's a `-webkit-` thing, but that's sort of obvious. I just don't know what I am doing wrong in my code. I am unable to post a fiddle of my working code, because the project is ongoing.

Is there a special property I should be using in for flexbox that I am not using? Thanks ahead of time for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, I got it licked. So for any of you Googlers out there, the way I fixed this is by changing the CSS to:

```
.card-grid {
  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;

  .data-card {
    /**
     * Height AUTO is important, because adding flex to the child makes it vertically 
     * stretch by default. So that means height: 100% won't work.
     */
    height: auto;
    //IE fallback
    display: inline-block;
    //Modern Browsers
    display: flex;
    display: -webkit-flex;

    ...

    /**
     * For some unknown reason, it still didn't work until I subracted 1% from
     * the width of each breakpoint I was using.
     */
    @media screen and (min-width: map_get($grid-breakpoints, 'lg')) {
      width: percentage((3 / 12)) - 1%;
    }

    @media screen and (min-width: map_get($grid-breakpoints, 'md')) {
      width: percentage((4 / 12)) - 1%;
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: map_get($grid-breakpoints, 'sm')) {
      width: percentage((6 / 12)) - 1%;
    }
  }
}
```

This solution still renders fine in Chrome, even with the `1%` of the true width  subracted. A few things that I discovered were:

1. Simply putting flex on the parent (to have the children's heights
   align) was not enough. I read a really great walkthrough on this
   [here](http://clearleft.com/thinks/270).
2. I was back to square one after I knew I had to keep flex on the
   parent and the *immediate* children. It wasn't until I set the
   widths of the children to `49%` that it was fixed. I still don't
   know why this is, because it's consistent with no `box-sizing:
   content-box` instead of what I am using which is `box-sizing:
   border-box`. I have a star selector putting `border-box` on every
   element, but perhaps I need to manually specify it on the child?
3. I didn't need all the extra vendor pre-fixes I had added, since in
   my case, I am using `display: inline-block` as a fallback when
   flexbox isn't available. Although, if I wanted to I could have used
   the below.

   ```
   @supports not (flex-wrap: wrap) {
     ...
   }
   ```

   Then put some code in there. Here's another post on [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/filling-space-last-row-flexbox/)
   that talks a little about using flexbox and fallbacks. Although, a
   different use-case than mine, it was still helpful. [This was a good visual reference](https://scotch.io/tutorials/a-visual-guide-to-css3-flexbox-properties) I'm thinking I'll keep around.

Hope all this information was helpful to someone. I know it saved my bacon.

**UPDATE:** Adding `box-sizing: border-box` to the child elements doesn't have any effect. Looks like subracting `1%` from the width is the way to go, unless there's something I don't know, which is more than possible.

**UPDATE 2:** Due to a suggestion from a friend, and [this article](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/flex/), I changed the code a little, started using the `flex` property, with column classes on the HTML as a fallback. Re-included the vendor prefixes in the form of a mixin. I also figured out the reason I was having to subtract percentages was because I had a grid container above the parent that had negative margins and clearfixes. Once this was removed the below CSS worked:

```
.card-grid {
  @include displayFlex;
  @include flexWrap(wrap);

  .data-card {
    /**
     * Height AUTO is important, because adding flex to the child makes it vertically 
     * stretch by default. So that means height: 100% won't work.
     */
    height: auto;
    //IE fallback
    display: inline-block;
    @include flexboxDisplay;
    @include flex(0 0 auto);

  }
}
```

Comment: I have the same problem but your solution didn't work for me. Could you please give a final code (not the solution), just for column-align purpose?

Comment: I'm sorry that it didn't work for you. If I'm understanding you correctly, I didn't use Flexbox's column-align property. I used typical column floats and widths -- due to the need to support old browsers, and not wanting to write tons more polyfills -- then used a wrapper with a clearfix on it. The important thing to note is the media queries in my first snippet. For my first solution, in order to get them to fit their columns, I had to subtract 1% from the true width and let Flexbox worry about the sizing.